# Revert to repo version and delete all new files I've created with Git

Tags: git

I want to remove all my local changes and revert to the repo version with Git. I've created new files which I haven't added or committed.

I've tried this command but it doesn't delete the new files I've created.

```
git reset --hard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git clean -fdx` will delete (recursively) all unversioned files. You can use this in tandem with `git checkout --` or `git reset --hard` to get a completely clean version of your repo.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the new files manually or execute `git clean -f` and after that execute `git stash`